# Multiply pandas DataFrame column with a Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

I want to multiply a pandas DataFrame `df` with Series `s`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,10],[0,1,11],[1,0,12],[1,1,13],[2,0,14],[2,1,15]], columns=['a','b','val'])
s = pd.Series([2,3])
```

```py
df:                s:
    a b val          
___________        ______
0   0 0 10         0   2
1   0 1 11         1   3
2   1 0 12
3   1 1 13
4   2 0 14
5   2 1 15
```

such that the indices of the Series [0, 1] are matched with column `b` of the DataFrame [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], i.e. I expect the column `val` to change from

```
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

to

```
[20, 33, 24, 39, 28, 45]
```

It seems like a trivial problem, and I tried `MultiIndex` and `GroupBy`, `.mul()` `.apply()` .... I just can't seem to figure it out. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map `s` on `b` then multiply by `val`:

```
df['val2'] = df['b'].map(s) * df['val']
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   a  b  val  val2
0  0  0   10    20
1  0  1   11    33
2  1  0   12    24
3  1  1   13    39
4  2  0   14    28
5  2  1   15    45

>>> df['b'].map(s)
0    2
1    3
2    2
3    3
4    2
5    3
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do index matching by using the `level` argument of `df.mul`:

```
>>> df['new_val'] = df.set_index('b', append=True)['val']
                      .mul(s, level=1)
                      .reset_index(drop=True)
```